# get the max child job record in the same table

Tags: sql

I have the below Job table where in we have 5 columns.

consider Job_id is primary key and parent_job_id will be null for the parent job and I have given the number values for the DATE column values 
for convenience..
pls consider the below table data

```
JOB_ID ABC XYZ        DATE PARENT_JOB_ID
     1 a   b            1            null   
     2 a   b            1             1 
     3 a   b            2             1 
     7 a   b            3             1 
     4 a   b            3            null  
     5 a   b            1             4 
     6 a   b            2             4
```

In this, I need to query in such a way that it should give me the below results,

```
JOB_ID ABC XYZ        PQR PARENT_JOB_ID
     1 a   b            1             null  
     7 a   b            3             1 
     4 a   b            3             null  
     6 a   b            2             4
```

they are the parent jobs + the latest child jobs only ( where the DATE value is max)

Please help/advise.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your database supports `row_number()` analytic function, then one way is to get

> the latest child jobs only ( where the DATE value is max)

using `row_number()` function.

then get parent jobs separately (`... where PARENT_JOB_ID is null`)

and then `UNION ALL` results from both queries.

Something like:

```
select * from (
    select JOB_ID, ABC, XYZ, DATE, PARENT_JOB_ID from (
        select *, row_number() over(partition by PARENT_JOB_ID order by DATE desc)  rn 
        from your_table 
        where PARENT_JOB_ID is not null
    ) t
    where rn = 1
    union all
    select JOB_ID, ABC, XYZ, DATE, PARENT_JOB_ID
    from your_table 
    where PARENT_JOB_ID is null
) t
order by coalesce(PARENT_JOB_ID, JOB_ID) , JOB_ID
```